# Routing Key events to other control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

Is there any standard way to route all Key events from the control `A` to other control `B`? I wish that the keyboard focus will still be on `A` however the event handler of `A` would trigger the all event handlers of `B` for the key events.

**edit:** Clarification: calling a specific event handler I wrote for `B` is not enough. I need to mimic the actual event. So for example I want that if a key is sent to a `TextBox`, it would be written to the `TextBox`. The solution given below does not do that (not to mention the fact that if new event handlers are added to `B` it completely fails).

I'm aware that WPF differentiates between logical focus and keyboard focus, but I need both focuses to remain on control `A`, but in a certain cases route its incoming event to other controls.

Comment: Can't you just make your key events for control A do some checking and if needed call the key events for Control B?

Comment: No! That wouldn't trigger the event, it'd just call a single specific function that was once associated with the button's click event. I want to simulate the actual event WPF sends.

Comment: @Elazar - See my edit. Would the `RaiseEvent()` method work instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     // Check if the event needs to be passed to button2's handler
     if (conditionIsMet)
     {
        // Send the event to button2
        button2.RaiseEvent(e);
     }
     else
     {
        // button1's "Click" code
     }
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     // button2's "Click" code
  }
```

**Edit:** Modified code to use the `RaiseEvent()` method to programmatically raise a specific event, rather than just calling the event handler for `button2`.

Comment: No! That wouldn't trigger the event, it'd just call a single specific function that was once associated with the button's click event. I want to simulate the actual event WPF sends.

Comment: I wonder why it's called raise events. I googled for fire event and invoke event and trigger event but with no results...